# Why so many pancakes, Deadpool?

Tags: comics, marvel, deadpool

[image]

So Deadpool seriously likes pancakes, but does he have any reason to make these? Is he eating them, feeding them to someone?

Comment: I've always thought of Deadpool as more of a waffle kind of guy.

Comment: Does Deadpool have superspeed? How long did it take to make 372,844 pancakes?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This, ladies and gentlemen, is Deadpool.

He made those 372,844 pancakes for one reason: a pratical joke, to slap some sense into his comrade.

If you continue the comic:
[image: Domino falls]
Oh no she is falling! what ever will happen next!
[image: she lands in a swimming pool full of pancakes]
Deadpool just likes to keep it real.

EDIT:
The comic on the Marvel site: [DEADPOOL (2008) #16](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/24950/deadpool_2008_16)